# MVC4 c# take a office word document, and convert to list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

So, I have a office word document. I need to go thru the document and get all the "words". I would then like to throw all those "words" in a List object. this is part one of my current problem.

part 2....
resource efficient way i can compare 2 "words" to see if they match. I found this .ddl i don't know if it's the right one tho...
http://diffplex.codeplex.com/

I found this code, in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555064/read-from-word-document-line-by-line), but there is a dependency on installing office on my server, this is a web application..

Comment: I have a question can you install office component in IIS?

Comment: @IamStalker i don't mind installing office, but you can't install office on IIS need to install it on the server where the IIS is

Comment: I just wanted to tell it will throw many exception, COM+ in CLR environment, wont work.

Comment: I'm too lazy today to write complete code for this, but here is a library that will enable the parsing of word document (assuming it is .docx) - http://docx.codeplex.com/. If it is .doc then you could look at IFilter interface in Windows.

Comment: Part 1 is pretty straight forward what about part 2 can you clarify a bit ? What do you mean by compare 2 "words" ? "Words" as in 2 word documents ? Or "words" as in 2 strings ? Or perhaps you want to compare the list from part 1 with another list and see if they match ? Clarify as much as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll provide an answer assuming I understand your question well enough, which for me was:

Part 1: Read the word document.

Part 2: Compare word documents, which I interpreted to compare the strings parsed from each word.

```
//Part 1
var applicationWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object filename = @"C:\Users\Omri\Desktop\Test.docx";
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc;

oDoc = applicationWord.Documents.Open(filename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                 ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                 ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                 ref missing, ref missing);
```

This is just to open the word document. You might have to install office on your server by the way, I saw you're good with that.

Now parsing the string - I provided a regex to remove all non alphanumeric characters from the string, that was my work assumption. You could change it to your liking. Also tested with pictures etc, it removes them.

```
var wordsList = new List<string>();
foreach (var range in oDoc.StoryRanges)
{
      var tempString = range.Text;
      tempString = Regex.Replace(tempString, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]", string.Empty);
      wordsList.AddRange(tempString.Split(new char[] { ' ' } ).ToList());
}
```

This leaves you with a list of strings that are in the word document.

```
//Part 2
bool wordMatch = data.Count == data2.Count; //quick initial check;
//you can check for wordMatch == false and return immediately

wordsList.Sort(); //sorting in lexicographical order so will be easy to compare
wordsList2.Sort(); //this is a 2nd word document
for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
       if (data.ElementAt(i) != data2.ElementAt(i))
       {
           wordMatch = false;
           break;
       }
}
```

That's it I think, hope it helps you.

Comment: @WingMan20-10 I referenced this dll: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll`

Answer (score 2):

Alright, with the limited info provided and without the clarifications, perhaps you can do something like this:

First of all get [Open XML SDK 2.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) (2.5MB). (you don't actually need to install it on the server you just need to reference a single `.dll` -> `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`.

Now you can write the following:

```
// This will extract the contents of a word doc and place them in an IEnumerable
// covering your first problem
private IEnumerable<string> ExtractContents(string filePath)
{
    using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {
        string content = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InnerText;
        return content.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}
```

Then you can just compare two lists doing something like:

```
IEnumerable<string> doc1 = ExtractContents(@"C:\doc1.docx");
IEnumerable<string> doc2 = ExtractContents(@"C:\doc2.docx");

if (doc1.SequenceEqual(doc2))
{
    // same content in both !
}
```

I hope I didn't misunderstand you.

Comment: if i don't have access to my webserver and file being uploaded via httpposted file, is there a way i can use this?

Comment: Yep just install the Open XML Sdk on your Dev machine and include the mentioned .dll in your build, basically you just need to reference the .dll :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can only provide a partial answer here, due to a problem which is not solvable for me and needs someone smarter than me :-)
Maybe you just find the section "The problems" helpful, because you might want to do research on this before you start implementing a solution.

**The use case**

I was wondering what use case might be behind your question, to better understand it. I am thinking of the following:
A user (maybe a professor) uploads 2 Word documents (maybe thesis documents) to the website in order to find out whether they are copies of each other.
You want the comparison by a list of words, because the documents may contain the same content but in different order (the student writing the thesis has reordered sentences).
The website user might want to have different views on the document content, but not the one which is built-in by Microsoft Word itself, because a) the user could compare the documents in Word directly, so there's no need to use the website and b) if the sentences have been reordered, comparison in Word is quite useless.

So, what might be useful?
As you already mentioned, we can extract a list of words out of the word documents. First of all, we want to count the words, so that we can later calculate the difference in percentage.
Then we compare the two lists and find the differences. We still get two lists: 1) words which are in document A but not in document B and 2) vice versa.
It might already be interesting to just display these two lists, but it seems you want to go one step further: display both Word document as a whole and highlight the differences.

**The problems**

- read a Word document. That should be pretty easy. I'd suggest [Codeplex DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) here, as I have used it before and it doesn't need Office installed. However, it works on Docx file format only.
- extract a list of words. A little bit more tricky, because we need to consider word delimiters, which might not only be spaces.
- Reduce the list to just the differences. This should be easy again.
- Display the differences. Probably the most tricky part if you want to get it right. You already make a proposal for a comparison component. However, I fear that such a component uses a built-in mechanism to find the differences - and that's exactly what I don't want, given my use case.
  But there's an even worse problem: highlighting the different words in the correct places. I'll need an example to describe it:

Word document A

> This is a sentence which is copied by the student. Then it contains
>   something else here.

Word document B

> This is a sentence which is copied by the student. Then it contains a
>   second sentence.

Words in document A which are not in document B: something, else, here.

Words in document B which are not in document A: a, second, sentence.

Let's do the difference highlighting now. In document A, it's not a problem: just highlight the words and it will be perfect.
In document B however, how do we know whether to highlight the words "a" and "sentence" in the first sentence or in the second sentence?

Of course, for humans it's immediately clear that the difference is in the second sentence as the first sentence is identical.
Things like that have probably been (or at least tried to be) solved by all the diff-tools out there already, I just wanted to mention that depending on the use case, it might be important to not barely break a word document down to a simple list of words.

**My solution**

Read a word document:

```
using Novacode;
DocX.Load(Path.Combine(mydocumentPath, @"DocumentA.docx"));
```

Extract a list of words:

```
private static IList<string> ExtractWords(DocX doc)
{
    // Get all the text without the headlines
    var text = doc.Text;
    // Maybe you want to tweak this and more items or use a different approach,
    // e.g. using Regex like proposed by @Omri Aharon
    var separators = "\r\n\"”“„?«» .!?,{}[]-".ToCharArray();
    var strings = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return strings.ToList();
}
```

Reduce the list to differences:

```
    private static void ReduceToDifferences(IList<string> wordsA, IList<string> wordsB)
    {
        // Maybe there's some optimization possible, 
        // e.g. loop over the list with fewest entries or something
        for (int i = wordsA.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // Find word of list A in list B
            var word = wordsA[i];
            var index = wordsB.IndexOf(word);

            // If found, remove it in both
            if (index > -1)
            {
                wordsB.RemoveAt(index);
                wordsA.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Display the differences: As mentioned, this is only a partial answer and for the problem described above, I do not provide a solution for this part.

**Short, self contained, correct example**

For the sake of completeness and to provide a SSCCE, here's the rest of my application to make it work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Novacode;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var wordsA = ExtractWords(DocX.Load(Path.Combine(mydocumentPath, @"DocumentA.docx")));
    var wordsB = ExtractWords(DocX.Load(Path.Combine(mydocumentPath, @"DocumentB.docx")));
    ReduceToDifferences(wordsA, wordsB);

    Console.WriteLine("------ Words only in A:");
    PrintList(wordsA);
    Console.WriteLine("------ Words only in B:");
    PrintList(wordsB);
    Console.WriteLine("------ Press any key");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void PrintList(IList<string> wordsA)
{
    foreach (var word in wordsA)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
}
```