# How to read a .docx file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, docx

When I read a .txt file it works and displays, but when I read a .docx file it reads but displays in XML format. How do I convert that XML format to .docx?

The code is:

```
protected void viewfile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          string path = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
          {
                  string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                  StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
                  foreach (string s in readText)
                  {
                          strbuild.Append(s);
                          strbuild.AppendLine();
                  }
                          TextBox1.Text = strbuild.ToString();
          }
}
```

Comment: Read a word document with this solution might be help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18555210/164155

Comment: The .docx file _is_ a number of separate files zipped up, and the files are XML.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference this , [Using DocxToText to Extract Text from DOCX Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20529/Using-DocxToText-to-Extract-Text-from-DOCX-Files).

You can extract text from `.docx` file like ,

```
DocxToText dtt = new DocxToText(docxFileName);
string text = dtt.ExtractText();
```

Answer (score 0):

There a library to manipulate docx, checkit out: http://docx.codeplex.com/