# Reading MS Word document in C#, dollar sign, special characters are ignored

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office

I am reading a word document (Word 97) word by word, returning text ignores dollar sign and any special characters. I have set encoding to
 `(var wordEncode = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;)` 
at document open time but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
var wordEncode = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
Document document = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Transcript.doc", ReadOnly: true, Encoding: wordEncode);

for (int i = 1; i < document.Words.Count; i++)
{
    textOftheWord = document.Words[i].Text.ToString().Trim().ToLower();
}
```

Example: document contains $587 but after reading it in a program, variable "textOftheWord" has 587, $ sign doesn't come through.Similarly, any special characters and numbers with decimals, all ignored.

Your help is greatly appreciated,Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read from word document line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555064/read-from-word-document-line-by-line)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object path = @"C:\Transcript.doc";
object readOnly = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
string totaltext = "";
for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
     totaltext += " \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(totaltext);
docs.Close();
word.Quit();
```

I was able to get $578 in the variable using that.

Similar question is asked here: [Read from word document line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555064/read-from-word-document-line-by-line)

Original answer here: http://mantascode.com/c-how-to-parse-the-text-content-from-microsoft-word-document/