# Insert word doc content into excel sheet cell

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

Is it possible to insert word document content into a cell in excel sheet programmatically using C# or open xml?

I want to read a docx file and insert the content into a cell in excel and save the excel file. I have a desktop application which displays the details about employees in a tabular form like first name, last name, age, salary, etc. There is a feature in my application which allows the user to export the tabular data into excel. One of my tabular data contains word document. So I want to read the word document contents for each employee and insert into excel file.

I have attached a sample image of the excel file. The feedback column is a contents of word file.

[image]

Comment: Assuming you can create ms-Excel from your application, you can read ms-Word following this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555064/read-from-word-document-line-by-line - However, be warned that the end user must have ms-Word installed. There are tools that allows the end user not have ms-Word.

Comment: Yes it is possible and it can be achieved by writing code. Did you do that?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I saw the sample code from the link, however, it only reads the word file contents as  strings. I am afraid that it may lose the formatting. I need to preserve the formatting as well. If the word had a table, then show the table in the excel too. This example will only read the contents as a plain string.

Comment: If you want the entire content you can embed the document into the cell? (As in Insert/Object/Create from file in the UI). Anything else and you'd have to copy/paste or "parse" the Word content pretty much byte-by-byte and convert it to the equivalent Excel objects - very complex and very slow.