# How can I parse a large DOCX file and pick out key words/strings that appear n number of times in python?

Tags: c#, nlp, tokenize, docx

I have very large DOCX files that I was hoping to parse through and be able to build a database of sorts that shows the frequency of a word/string in the documents. From what I gather this is definitely not an easy task. I was just hoping for some direction as to a library that I could use to help me with this.

[image]

This is an example of what one may look like. The structure isn't consistent so that will complicate things as well. Any direction will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you bound to C++? We're doing similar things in our pipeline but primarily using Python since Python has Spacy, which is very fast and accurate for NLP.

Comment: Seems like a job for regex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555064/read-from-word-document-line-by-line

Comment: @T.Altena I guess I am not bound to c#, we have other components for the project in .NET so I considered it primary only because I felt it might be easier down the road. Maybe I will try the python route! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Python based solution

If (as per your comment) you're able to do this in Python, look at the following snippets:

So first thing to realise is that docx files are actually .zip archives containing a number of XML files. Most text-content will be stored in the `word/document.xml`. Word does some complicated things with numbered lists, which will require you to also load other XMLs like `styles.xml`.

The markup of DOCX files can be a pain as the document is structured in w:p (paragraphs) and arbitrary w:r (runs). These runs are basically 'a bit of typing', so it can either be one letter, or a couple of words together.

We use UpdateableZipFile from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35435548. This was primarily because we also wanted to be able to edit the documents, so you could potentially just use snippets from it.

```
import UpdateableZipFile
from lxml import etree

source_file = UpdateableZipFile(os.path.join(path, self.input_file))
nsmap = {'w': "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main",
         'mc': "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006",
        } #you might need a few more namespace definitions if you get funky docx inputs

document = source_file.read_member('word/document.xml') #returns the root of an Etree object based on the document.xml xml tree.

# Query the XML element using xpaths (don't use Regex), this gives the text of all paragraph nodes:
paragraph_list = document.xpath("//w:p/descendant-or-self::*/text()", namespaces=self.nsmap)
```

You can then feed the text to NLP such as Spacy:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
word_counts = {}

for paragraph in paragraph_list:
    doc = nlp(paragraph)
    for token in doc:
        if token.text in word_counts:
            word_counts[token.text]+=1
        else:
            word_counts[token.text]=1
```

[Spacy](https://spacy.io) will tokenize the text for you, and can do lots more in terms of Named Entity Recognition, Parts of Speech tagging etc.